# Is there a way to divide id's of table for specific type of data in a table in mariadb/mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a requirement to have data in a table, in which the id(auto-increment) should be divided for specific type of data.

Types, for example - Type1, Type2, Type3 and Type4

```
Type   | Offset
Type1  | 1 -100
Type2  | 101-200
Type3  | 201-300
Type4  | 302-400
```

If the data is inserted to table defined below, then based on the type the id should be set and auto-incremented.

For example,

```
Capability_id  |  Capability_name | type
---------------------------------------------
1              |  Type1_cap1      | Type1
2              |  Type1_cap2      | Type1
101            |  Type2_cap1      | Type2
3              |  Type1_cap3      | Type1
```

Is there a way to achieve this in mariadb/mysql?

Comment: This is a mistake. Feel free to make it.

Comment: Mistake? Is this impossible to achieve, is what you mean?

Comment: I mean it's a mistake to attempt to do so. The id (typically a simple surrogate PRIMARY KEY) should have no such constraints imposed upon it.

Comment: Is `Capability_id` defined explicitly or extracted from the `Offset`? Which one suppose to be auto-increment?

Comment: What happens when capability id for type 1 wants to increment to 101?

Comment: @tcadidot0 capability_id is auto_incremented.

Comment: @P.Salmon, 1 to 100 is something which is estimated to some large enough value for respective type. It will not be reaching more that 100 for type1

Comment: So values in `Type` column are auto populated based on `Capability_id`?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Yes. Type is actually not required. If based on offset is working fine, will remove type

Answer (score 0):

If the `type` has been pre-defined to a fixed range of ids, I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT capability_id,CASE 
       WHEN capability_id BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN CONCAT("Type1_cap",capability_id)
       WHEN capability_id BETWEEN 101 AND 200 THEN CONCAT("Type2_cap",capability_id-100)
       WHEN capability_id BETWEEN 201 AND 300 THEN CONCAT("Type3_cap",capability_id-200)
       WHEN capability_id BETWEEN 301 AND 400 THEN CONCAT("Type4_cap",capability_id-300)
END as `Capability_name`
FROM mytable;
```

Fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bG3mVwoNX66NBEgqLxX7Ya/0